# Combinations with repetition formula

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

Why doesn't $\frac{n^r}{r!}$ work in combinations with repetition?

I know the idea of stars and bars well and know the law of ${n+r-1}\choose{r}$ but I don't understand why the first formula shouldn't work like we first calculate the whole number of different arrangements with allowing repetitions then we divide by the factorial of $r$ to make it without order.

Comment: Because the factorial takes out too much. Consider the case of rolling two dice. Sure, there are $2!$ ways of rolling a 3 and a 4 (roll first a 3, then a 4; or roll first a 4 and then a 3). But there is only **one** way, not 2, of rolling a double 1.

Comment: Extending the comment of @ArturoMagidin, consider the case of three dice.  There are $~3!~$ ways of rolling $~\{1,2,3\},~$ in some order, only $~3~$ ways of rolling $~\{1,2,2\}~$ in some order, and only $~1~$ way of rolling $~\{2,2,2\}.~$ Notice that $$6^3 = \left[ ~3! \times \binom{6}{3}~\right] + \left[ ~3 \times \frac{6!}{(6-2)!}~\right] + \left[ ~1 \times \binom{6}{1}~\right].$$

Answer (score 0):

You need to be very clear in balls-bins problems as to which elements are distinct, and which are identical.

Your first formula's numerator, $n^r$ assumes that each of $r$ *distinct* balls has $n$ *distinct* boxes to go to. Furthermore, as pointed out by Arturo Magidin, dividing by $r!$ make no sense in the context.

On the other hand, stars and bars deals with putting *identical* balls to *distinct* boxes

Various types of problems are there for balls in bins, and you are encouraged to go through [The Twelvefold Way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelvefold_way) to get an idea of why different situations are dealt with differently